# How do I delete everything after the 3rd 4rth occurrence of a character using sed/grep/regex

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I need some help: looking for a way to remove everything after the nth occurrence (most likely 4th or 5th) of "/" in a hyperlink using command like that

```bash
cat text.txt | grep -o "^((?:[^/]*/){5}).*$"
```

This command is not working for me. For example, if I have

```
https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/?toURL=https://forbes.com/&refURL=&referrer=
```

My desired output is:

```
https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/
```

Additionally, if a link only has < 4 `/`, I'd like to keep everything.

Comment: Browsing the internet shown me that maybe you can use `cut -d / -f -5`?

Comment: @JvdV, Good thought but this will even work if `?` is not present in line IMHO, just a thought here, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, right, I didn't notice that it was a requirement to match upto `?`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5):

***1st solution:*** With `awk` please try following. It should cover both scenarios where `/?` OR `?` is coming in URLs(which could be the case in an actual request). Simply making field separator as `/?\\?` for all the lines of your Input_file and printing 1st field of line if line starts from either `http` OR `https`.

```
awk -F'/?\\?' '/^https?:\/\//{print $1}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `awk` with using its `match` function please try following solution, little complex compare to first solution but you can try it in case you need more values to be checked apart from getting values before `?` at that time it can help you since it saves values into array.

```
awk 'match($0,/^(https?:\/\/([^?]*))\?/,arr1){print arr1[1]}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `?` question mark can be where to exclude from, you can try this `sed`

```
$ sed 's/?.*//' input_file
https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can match the protocol, and if available use grep `-P` repeating a non capture group matching 3 times `/` after it:

```
grep -oP "^https?://(?:[^/]*/){3}" text.txt
```

Or grep `-E` repeating a capture group:

```
grep -oE "^https?://([^/]*/){3}" text.txt
```

Or just grep `-o` with the right escapes:

```
grep -o "^https\?://\([^/]*/\)\{3\}" text.txt
```

Example

```
echo "https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/?toURL=https://forbes.com/&refURL=&referrer=" | grep -oP "^https?://(?:[^/]*/){3}"
```

Output

```
https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/
```

Note that you don't have to use `cat text.txt |`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `grep` that would work in any version of `grep`:

```bash
grep -oE '([^/]*/){5}' file

https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/
```

Similarly this `sed` would also work:

```bash
sed -E 's~(([^/]*/){5}).*~\1~' file

https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/
```

Both these solutions will grab first 5 tokens delimited by `/`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> awk 'NF<_||NF=_' FS=/ OFS=/ \_=5
> ```

```
   https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `?` question mark can be where to exclude from, you could try:

```bash
cut -d '?' -f1 input_file
```